# se puede poner estilos personalizados a ciertas palabras sin necesidad de poner la palabra dentro de una etiqueta?

Tags: java, html, css

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, aspernatur commodi consequatur corporis dolore
  dolorem error ex fuga maxime minima molestiae nisi nostrum quas quibusdam quidem rem repudiandae sequi vitae?

quisiera poner un estilo a la palabra consectetur hay alguna manera de hacerlo sin necesidad de ponerla dentro de una etiqueta es decir solo darle estilo a esa palabra

Comment: Que has intentado?, Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Pierde sentido completamente utilizar HTML si quieres lograr ese objetivo.

Comment: Tengo entendido que no es posible amigo